# Too Many Rails Routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails application right now and the site currently has about 30 routes(map.connect). I expect that to eventually reach about 60 or 70. Is there any side effect of having lots of routes? I guess I'm just paranoid! :) Thanks

Comment: This question would've been a lot easier to give an answer to if you provided us with your routes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails routes and site performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176202/rails-routes-and-site-performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: 70 routes a problem?

No, it works fine. My Rails project has about 1000 and it works fine.

(It has that many because a scaffold that I use, Hobo, is automatically creating them)

Comment: wow, how many resources is that? I thought RoR is supposed to ease the URI management but 1000 seems excessive.

Comment: I have 1067 in my app (this is Rails 2.3, so it was almost 2000 before they removed the formatted_* routes).  The routes.rb is only 240 lines.  I have 109 controllers and 124 models.

Answer (score 1):

660 in my non-scaffold application. Only problem is `rake routes` takes a tick to load.

Answer (score 0):

No but I recommend checking out the guide just in case you missed something: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

See @stephenmurdoch's answer here: [Rails routes and site performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176202/rails-routes-and-site-performance)

70 may not affect performance, but too many routes may.